# $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-e^{-u^2/2}]^\infty_{-\infty}+\mu = \mu$

Tags: integration

$$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-e^{-u^2/2}]^\infty_{-\infty}+\mu = \mu$$

I know $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-e^{-u^2/2}]^\infty_{-\infty}=1$, but then the answer should be $\sigma+\mu$ right?

---

*see last 2 lines*

[image]

Comment: If you plug $\pm\infty$ into $e^{-u^2/2}$, you get $e^{-\infty} = 0$. So it's $0-0=0$, and not $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DanielFischer, $[-e^{-u^2/2}]^{\infty}_{-\infty} = 0$